# Гистограмма не изменяется после удаления данных через drop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Пытаюсь drop хоть до, хоть прописания гистограммы вписывать, ничего не изменяется на гистограмме

!!! После переприсваивания df ничего не изменилось!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sns 
%matplotlib inline

file_name = 'variant_25'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name + '.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates() #Удаление дубликатов
df = df.drop(['B'], axis=1) #Удаление аномально большого количества данных "B"
df = df.fillna(value="ffill")
#df.drop(index=('B'))
print(df.info(verbose=True))
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)}) #Аномальные данные. Начало
sns.displot(df['PTRATIO'], bins=30)
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось где? Ошибка с `None` исчезла, для начала? Далее. Как по-вашему удаление одного столбца может отразиться на рисовании гистограммы совсем другого столбца? Кроме того, вы рисуете **распределение** значений. То есть их счётчик. У вас в `df` много значений, равных примерно `17`. Вы хотите выбросить эти значения или что? Это не аномальные величины, это, можно так сказать, аномальное количество каких-то величин. Да и то, что такое аномалия - вопрос философский. В любом случае, чтобы вам помогали дальше - предоставьте ваши данные или хотя бы их фрагмент, чтобы было о чём говорить.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(['B'], axis=1)
...
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Вы никуда не присваиваете результаты действий с датафреймом. Нужно присваивать изменённый датафрейм обратно в переменную `df`:

```
df = df.drop(['B'], axis=1)
...
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```